# How do i make the variable work using the input field?

Tags: php, forms, post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>MAD LIBS</h3>
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $pluralNoun = $_POST['pluralNoun'];
        $celebrity = $_POST['celebrity'];
      }

      echo "Roses are " . $color;
      echo $pluralNoun . " are Blue";
      echo "I love " . $celebrity;
     ?>

    <form action="site.php" method="post">
      Color: <input type="text" name="color"> <br>
      Plural Noun: <input type="text" name="pluralNoun"> <br>
      Celebrity: <input type="text" name="celebrity"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br>
    </form>



    <!-- <?php
      if (isset($_POST['color']) && isset($_POST['pluralNoun']) && isset($_POST['celebrity'])) :
        echo "Roses are " . $_POST['color'] . "<br>";
        echo $_POST['pluralNoun'] . " are Blue <br>";
        echo "I love " . $_POST['celebrity'];
      endif;
     ?> -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Hey guys, I'm completly new to PHP. Can you guys help me how to get this code working? The bottom php code that i commented out is working. But I wanted to use the first php code so i can call ($_POST['']) using variables. But in the website it shows:

> Warning: Undefined variable $color in C:\xampp\htdocs\webProgramming\site.php on line 16
> Roses are
> Warning: Undefined variable $pluralNoun in C:\xampp\htdocs\webProgramming\site.php on line 17
> are Blue
> Warning: Undefined variable $celebrity in C:\xampp\htdocs\webProgramming\site.php on line 18
> I love

I'm sorry for my bad english, it's not my first langauge. I hope you understand what my questions mean.

Comment: `<!-- <?php...` not sure if commenting like this works. If you don't want to use that php block, rather you can comment the code inside php block using `/* ... */`.

Comment: In your first part, move your `if`s closing bracket `}` to after your `echo`s

Comment: Move `echo "Roses are " . $color;
      echo $pluralNoun . " are Blue";
      echo "I love " . $celebrity;` inside the first `if`. Currently you're trying to output them regardless of whether they were actually defined or not, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For top part of the code you have 2 solutions

1. Put all in `if` statement

   ```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $pluralNoun = $_POST['pluralNoun'];
        $celebrity = $_POST['celebrity'];

        echo "Roses are " . $color ."<br>";
        echo $pluralNoun . " are Blue <br>";
        echo "I love " . $celebrity ."<br>";
    }
   ```
2. Or you can use ternary

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $color = $_POST['color'];
       $pluralNoun = $_POST['pluralNoun'];
       $celebrity = $_POST['celebrity'];
   }

   echo "Roses are " . ($color ?? "[valu not set]") ."<br>";
   echo ($pluralNoun ?? "[valu not set]") . " are Blue" ."<br>";
   echo "I love " . ($celebrity ?? "[valu not set]") ."<br>";
   ```

Comment: Thank you! A few more questions: what does ternary means? What's the difference between the 1st solution? What do you think better to use for a solution?

Comment: Ternary is short version of `if / else` [ternary tutorial](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-ternary-operator/). And php 8 has shorter version of ternary with `??`. There is no better solution, maybe the first one is a little cleaner to read the code.